# How to use Azure Powershell Datafactory cmdlets against specific branches in Azure DevOps repositories?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory, powershell-cmdlet, azure-git-deployment

I have a Datafactory in AzureDevOps Repos. 
[image]

I am trying to use Azure Powershell cmdlets to create a trigger, such as the following :[image]

The problem is, when I run the above command, the changes are **not showing** on the Az DevOps Repo. So the trigger I just created does not appear in the Repo.

As a workaround, I have been able to manually create JSON files in my local git repo > merge with local master > push to online master and then the trigger works just fine and the JSON file is also visible in the Az DevOps Repo.
[image]

But how to instruct the Powershell cmdlets to work on a specific branch? Because when I just use PS cmdlets, whatever is added (trigger/dataset/pipeline) does not show up online in the Azure DevOps Repo.

So, question is, where do cmdlets like **Set-AzDatafactorV2Trigger** operate/make the changes and can that be changed to work against specific branches in a git repo?

Comment: I tested and use Set-AzDatafactorV2Trigger to set triggers. But the triggers cannot be found on the ui portal. And the repo is not updated. Set triggers from Ui portal works fine

Comment: Precisely. Using these cmdlets, the repo does not update. Nor do they show up on the UI. Would you suggest I avoid using the cmdlets if I am working from Powershell and would like the repo to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you run powershell commands against a Data Factory which is connected to git, the updates are made to the "live mode" of ADF and not the the   git version of the factory.

Have you tried to switch to "live mode" to see if your triggers are there:
[image]